# Can the differentials in a minimal free resolution ever have a "long" row of $0$'s?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Assume just for sake of simplicity that $R = k[x_1 , \dots , x_n]$ is a standard graded polynomial ring over a field. If one considers the ideal
$$I = \left({x}_{1}{x}_{3},{x}_{2}^{2},{x}_{2}{x}_{3},{x}_{3}^{2}\right)$$
and computes the minimal free resolution, the very last differential takes the form
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
x_3 \\
0 \\
-x_2 \\
x_1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This means that the very back differential has a "row" of $0$'s. My question is the following: is it possible to have a differential appearing in a minimal free resolution (of a cyclic module, say) with an entire row being equal to $0$ (and the row has length at least $2$).

Computationally, I have found many "near-miss" examples, where the differentials have a very long row and a single nonzero entry. It seems that I can never quite get a long row of $0$'s. Also, in the Cohen-Macaulay case this is definitely impossible since a row of $0$'s would correspond to a column of $0$'s in the minimal free resolution of the canonical module.

Any example (or explanation of why this cannot happen) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can not comment on the other's posts as commenting needs at least  50 reputation, I'm forced to release an answer. It seems  that the second power, $I^2$, of  your ideal $I$ has a zero row of length 4. Compute it via Macaulay2 and look at the  matrix of the very last differential.

Comment: This is certainly an answer to my question. The row of zeros gets even longer as one increases the powers, too, so it looks like it becomes arbitrarily long.